# my nav bar is not working ( bootstrap integrated with ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, navbar, bootstrap-modal

˚
my style(css)

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #fed136;
  font-family: "Kaushan Script", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, cursive;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand.active {
  color: #fec503;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #fed136;
  border-color: #fed136;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.navbar-default .nav li a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
}
.navbar-default .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav li a:focus {
  color: #fed136;
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #fed136;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: white;
  background-color: #fec503;
}



.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inner {
  background:transparent;
}
.navbar li { color: #000 }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 25px 0;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.3s;
    transition: padding 0.3s;
    border: none;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .navbar-default.navbar-shrink {
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .navbar-default.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

how i insert this css

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'test' %>`
it's path : /assets/stylesheet/test.css

actually those code are copied from the following template
http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/
but i dont know why my nav bar is not transparent

I am using bootstrap integrated with ruby on rails

Comment: Is your CSS not applying or your CSS file is not getting included...Please check..

Comment: I dont think so, because there is backgrond image set for the header in the same css file, and it works

Comment: That means your CSS file is getting included, then you should check for your CSS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you install the Bootstrap gem make sure you changed `application.css` to `application.scss`

Put your styles in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

The in your `application.scss` you can `@import test.css`

Comment: But I have @import test.css in my application.css.sass already